# Elasticsearch - Is elasticsearch possible without HTTP (offline mode)

Tags: elasticsearch, offline, elasticsearch-plugin

I have an app in android, ios and windows which works in offline mode. That is, content is stored in the local database. Now I am trying to implement elasticsearch on this app. Is it possible to search the data from local database when I am offline. Or, is there a way to access Elasticsearch without HTTP.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is no, Since elasticsearch will be installed outside of your phone.

But one of the options could be [FTS3](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html). Its not as powerful as ES but could be solution.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will check with FTS3.

Comment: You might also want to check Firebase with Flashlight integration.

Comment: Thanks for comment @Val. But this will again be working with HTTP. I want a solution in which I can use ES in offline mode (either without HTTP or having the server within mobile)

Comment: Then no, that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks @Val for clarification.

Comment: A smartphone has simply way too limited resources to run an ES server.